# How to Reclaim Space from XenServer?

Tags: xen, lvm, xenserver, snapshot

I found that the XenCenter storage tab claims there is 1096.6 GB used of 1107.7 GB total (708.5 GB allocated).  It appears that some space has been eaten and not released.

The SMLog shows:

```
[13816] 2014-03-28 15:12:00.881524  Got sm-config for *c64fff0a[VHD](60.000G//43.586G|ao): {'vmhint': 'beb3db6c-19c3-dae1-c043-eb7e813e2f42', 'vdi_type': 'vhd', 'vhd-blocks': 'eJzt1EENACAMBLDD+aTNGYTwQcPSimjl2QAAMEMH4HNjqGQdHo3WeQ=='}
[13816] 2014-03-28 15:12:00.897075  Got sm-config for *a4d787b8[VHD](50.000G//2.066G|ao): {'vmhint': '4f319162-e3c9-e511-1334-8728fdfadc17', 'vdi_type': 'vhd', 'vhd-blocks': 'eJx7/5+Dg4OBgeF9AwMDiPGCAQKgtP3/P2Ba/P//n/+BYP5/CPgOpeX/PwDLCzCgAkJ8YoH8/w9k6sRvP7HuoZb95AKY/eSGH7XsHygw6n/62I8rfGH2w/I5vcFgCX/5AbZ/oAAi/iHgwQDZP9D5f7DFP73CA2a/DJ3sw2X/QIFR+39A6QHJ/kj2/2OQbyBeH7XyB4r/H9C/FkQL/wMS9La/Ab88M4bAfwT4Qdh8RgCVu36z'}
[13816] 2014-03-28 15:12:00.908517  Got sm-config for *d80380f3[VHD](100.000G//23.312G|ao): {'vdi_type': 'vhd', 'vhd-blocks': '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'}
[13816] 2014-03-28 15:12:00.929613  Got sm-config for *51eb7244[VHD](50.000G//1.785G|ao): {'vhd-parent': '9d42bd27-d82b-4b1e-9c5c-d48981f9c250', 'vdi_type': 'vhd', 'vhd-blocks': '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'}
[13816] 2014-03-28 15:12:00.945872  Got sm-config for *06a36888[VHD](150.000G//95.082G|ao): {'vmhint': '27ad1d66-59ab-1151-cab6-95bbb184baa8', 'vdi_type': 'vhd', 'vhd-blocks': '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'}
[13816] 2014-03-28 15:12:00.958073  Got sm-config for *c2b970a3[VHD](150.000G//6.109G|ao): {'vhd-parent': '06a36888-75d3-4677-afd9-fe33f38ea922', 'vdi_type': 'vhd', 'vmhint': '27ad1d66-59ab-1151-cab6-95bbb184baa8', 'vhd-blocks': 'eJztWn1sFEUUf7Mzt3tgWzZA9Iy1XZRA//CjAUwxIm5JsZo0xsQoGgkc0ShCkA9NJFi4AYvFiKEhiI0hCgmJMfEPE2MKppFBCMU/TNB/xJDQNZpACIkXIXIJ11vfzO71rtdr76PbrURe2n0zs2/e783Xm5m3x0ER5x6PCOKl1t+dhF3rnrZVJgphkQGa4jWhIRbie+0nDU6u8AX8j4eFr3n45nARCwc5iz+1ZHBiS05cnz5q/yxije4EswPF8M+4NNeMxmW9RZ/XAZzs5led2mMxsRDeqoGTWH4tvd2peSxZ79dr6Y4BBwMVpzsLsTkjoEsbkjlzhjrwIYx0rkQoprmpxFA0kTbSRgazW4HbYy8Trfz2M19YL79KIER8HjZuIRmO4UjOLOqmGgBo4uJiG/OkPydjY0db1xPTcdABZgeML4wf5dIzzsP+1/zOwGkB+g2FnKTcgiZXtKCbTKTH0VM1PryNExF5gwhcd8TnRLwz1LfZnnH63fe8fEYiIjdSzQ8eIeKNF5+85vZlBDW9aUGS3Kv47MTwmW8B0+6TWkHX4moN60p9Lf/FYiql9xerPXFivhcx/FnDZzJogvdV6UppSX2ecCQvbUIJKq9jdInMaoD8uUY8VbbVwZEBxjkwbORpSAy6GcN1yqiFTq0edrA4dsISjUnvRN2dHEzLkl3ElV6I7kKu6cqPWMYFr6YO0yRbTPcDaYtCjQ6kN7Y0z7ev2D7ryvNdMbrlp09p5gl66berDo6FyeQCl4qjy8ACEjVUmsHrh4kj90V9gO+00ZB26afbTHwv4kJrw53bG19m4W5twWGjB+2zhMaOoln2PLSHXLeAchaFWKu5BvQvlbh9pk1oUAum8rw7CRh/c3UAaX/1Yv9fL1/Y5q4/8UjfZWC7e7x2Ua7ptg2wa04nsHrag2m02Ib5a5tVjxgbNqw+kVjVtxo+/uCBb3/9bulBYr3CdDPC4RSaT4v08QI4ZFJj0N13cuNN9ybnW7ZfS2OHDA66AwlBX1ouhSwqANYgrty9XF7JyHvEfC+vkRKCk0Qs3KPMKMK9hSueOC4uR76evhLqpzkxHVoOLZPlZF0cdjgWph62lhxFW+kd9wzt+2IPXTJ35RxhNEW7j3fhS8Zaz3r62v/BShrnXQQrmRTo6f5FFp8j5rFNuGY00Hd34IS4/2y93Cno44JJR2L0TEHLbxFqdKuoRFNUSAdNrnxSb+e/MKGtqLyLBzaryIsm6IS98zoZh2Yce1eutpJEuLeaSTI6/3w58hI8KCLS70iyg9N5KxGBPEdWco++TbcpWPIjJf9ffGeK8ZOlZSYVPzXF+GO23woJn8yUWyzxg3WHV6SKhw82FeTtvIQJUO1xFPHVkZ00e/nh0+X+ZTkhGZPZUSVASXx4DvKhF3tpjreHE+lVkwM6Ap/ErPElpI8QDTLJx5NrHnErISOF5ZhSJVOo3SkZ2dKy6n3KokSxTJSoW5Kw/wvnG/1hONmYhF5YOFGMcfFTsIB7SdscdQqrIOhXLX4SZvBc1vj+8qO6sQfe3ApOJWqaTeoSjpfy310BZyrBLwaztRLoidF/YP9hHPLiGapUBi2l17HDwM+upxpHPuUZeK76dBLKVRvxIyMLAAbE5OMOwzlZR2U0Cqh+H6kaPwUHbck3ybAYQ1tm77XBbD0gLToX6U0A3igzDUCHygq0VY7vQNcYr0IJtJABfkzxgmKP2cXtCfADA86/nJPlwektGz/lfS4bbr+lMss7rKzAbA3twr3B4ipPVTzUDgw/CbN4fsHaMutJi3lJsdJ60vBVtu1i4uoqxy91/rfjoq6ld/M3Wf8sgsYnH+ajyVluF5HLfhbkwcLL+bctL+tFQIo7wdaDAWMrKKeggNvh/VAA1PjHKpGXHdQULH5lNJa3rhY/Re7iku/NlWkiWIxx8ZNQpxJWXll48BI/1PlWBP9OxTfa+GxkdaVc+wGfc8iGpkfv0yyvN7m/W8apg7P3j+6HTsV/nn8joXxZqmD/y6OwQqG4/gv7P9QjGMmQ2iyoBWNferJGyt9W3PtMYiCoSUO4d7ElZyeg5F/4joYG'}
[13816] 2014-03-28 15:12:00.970209  Got sm-config for *cc198ad1[VHD](20.000G//2.047G|ao): {'vdi_type': 'vhd', 'vhd-blocks': 'eJxb////+Q4GBgYQ5uBgYFjBAAEdEMqGgQVMi/9HBdNhjPsN8v+B8gIMqIAQn1ggwCABpuVRrW8g3Rzy3INkP9CjD0i1lmIAsx8S/j/IDkfy7YfYKI8W9jJ0th/i/wcM8nSyF91++Q8QvvwfetuPLf0/oIE9uMSh/qezvxH2EwKM///h083/Hy/4BwCjZn3t'}
[13816] 2014-03-28 15:12:00.982033  Got sm-config for *bff9b729[VHD](60.000G//7.660G|ao): {'vhd-parent': 'c64fff0a-51ea-4d68-baa5-bdcf69583213', 'vdi_type': 'vhd', 'vmhint': 'beb3db6c-19c3-dae1-c043-eb7e813e2f42', 'vhd-blocks': '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'}
[13816] 2014-03-28 15:12:00.994156  Got sm-config for *0fb4f6e0[VHD](100.000G//2.188G|ao): {'vhd-parent': 'd80380f3-d02a-491a-bd50-75950760b433', 'vdi_type': 'vhd', 'vhd-blocks': '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'}
[13816] 2014-03-28 15:12:01.006264  Got sm-config for 9c786065[VHD](150.000G//119.297G|ao): {'vdi_type': 'vhd', 'vhd-blocks': 'eJzt18EJgDAMheF0BgdwFEfz6FGcSEepeHAFD9KIR6FFlGoE/+8QaEPhEXLpUKmIOC+icW3i/tysGm4/vq8Mfbq51Dq+lgTAI5bqcJz20qh6iyzZrNYBLugK6wQAAABAXJDPctazAQAAAIDcrD9a+BTHTgD4MbeXDWY+qKg='}
[13816] 2014-03-28 15:12:01.020762  Got sm-config for *9d42bd27[VHD](50.000G//23.953G|ao): {'vdi_type': 'vhd', 'vhd-blocks': 'eJzllrEOwiAQQO/ESEf/wB81KX/i6uYvsPkbbK5NHHSo4pUWbYm0BREH33IBSt9xQMJBEwLEHgCKAjgwaODaTzkyZjnqK8SwogyG/qjfwHKi7Z/n+vWd65ryygMXXDj+WXCVyK9m+xXXVRppjyWsYeAXyRU96LQbySWw2qm4B+9zWuo/99v6n37kr2GTU3dl5jYxz/BZS3MrFs4tmWr7II8czlvZft1c7DabcMLzmZvxV2CCAVLEZtU1Rdn2o/OdbSMdy7HxILCCrYmls9mftucisQK7+AluY4PGv3t9tnGm3px/dM8PlKje+EVMLaPqr7r1l6+K5HIbr3i7/mxpPP3d+lUWa89PGZgY+R5N4G/j5On/kNLTX6HZ6a/7fdg6+MYfn+3zTA=='}
[13816] 2014-03-28 15:12:01.021241  Found 2 VDIs for deletion:
[13816] 2014-03-28 15:12:01.021394    *f210efdf[VHD](150.000G//150.301G|ao)
[13816] 2014-03-28 15:12:01.021528    9c786065[VHD](150.000G//119.297G|ao)
[13816] 2014-03-28 15:12:01.021838  Deleting unlinked VDI *f210efdf[VHD](150.000G//150.301G|ao)
[13816] 2014-03-28 15:12:01.070941  lock: tried lock /var/lock/sm/dcd084f1-6074-dc53-e43e-88de1606e09e/sr, acquired: True (exists: True)
[13816] 2014-03-28 15:12:01.071058  ['/usr/sbin/lvremove', '-f', '/dev/VG_XenStorage-dcd084f1-6074-dc53-e43e-88de1606e09e/VHD-f210efdf-1916-4c5d-b25c-19cc69814c22']
[13816] 2014-03-28 15:12:01.143921  FAILED in util.pread: (rc 5) stdout: '', stderr: '  Can't remove open logical volume "VHD-f210efdf-1916-4c5d-b25c-19cc69814c22"
'
[13816] 2014-03-28 15:12:01.144117  *** lvremove failed on attempt #0
[13816] 2014-03-28 15:12:01.144204  ['/usr/sbin/lvremove', '-f', '/dev/VG_XenStorage-dcd084f1-6074-dc53-e43e-88de1606e09e/VHD-f210efdf-1916-4c5d-b25c-19cc69814c22']
[13816] 2014-03-28 15:12:01.220172  FAILED in util.pread: (rc 5) stdout: '', stderr: '  Can't remove open logical volume "VHD-f210efdf-1916-4c5d-b25c-19cc69814c22"
'
[13816] 2014-03-28 15:12:01.220424  *** lvremove failed on attempt #1
[13816] 2014-03-28 15:12:01.220526  ['/usr/sbin/lvremove', '-f', '/dev/VG_XenStorage-dcd084f1-6074-dc53-e43e-88de1606e09e/VHD-f210efdf-1916-4c5d-b25c-19cc69814c22']
[13816] 2014-03-28 15:12:01.288279  FAILED in util.pread: (rc 5) stdout: '', stderr: '  Can't remove open logical volume "VHD-f210efdf-1916-4c5d-b25c-19cc69814c22"
'
[13816] 2014-03-28 15:12:01.288607  *** lvremove failed on attempt #2
[13816] 2014-03-28 15:12:01.288743  ['/usr/sbin/lvremove', '-f', '/dev/VG_XenStorage-dcd084f1-6074-dc53-e43e-88de1606e09e/VHD-f210efdf-1916-4c5d-b25c-19cc69814c22']
[13816] 2014-03-28 15:12:01.351970  FAILED in util.pread: (rc 5) stdout: '', stderr: '  Can't remove open logical volume "VHD-f210efdf-1916-4c5d-b25c-19cc69814c22"
'
[13816] 2014-03-28 15:12:01.352192  *** lvremove failed on attempt #3
[13816] 2014-03-28 15:12:01.352277  ['/usr/sbin/lvremove', '-f', '/dev/VG_XenStorage-dcd084f1-6074-dc53-e43e-88de1606e09e/VHD-f210efdf-1916-4c5d-b25c-19cc69814c22']
[13816] 2014-03-28 15:12:01.426555  FAILED in util.pread: (rc 5) stdout: '', stderr: '  Can't remove open logical volume "VHD-f210efdf-1916-4c5d-b25c-19cc69814c22"
'
[13816] 2014-03-28 15:12:01.426766  *** lvremove failed on attempt #4
[13816] 2014-03-28 15:12:01.426846  ['/usr/sbin/lvremove', '-f', '/dev/VG_XenStorage-dcd084f1-6074-dc53-e43e-88de1606e09e/VHD-f210efdf-1916-4c5d-b25c-19cc69814c22']
[13816] 2014-03-28 15:12:01.508677  FAILED in util.pread: (rc 5) stdout: '', stderr: '  Can't remove open logical volume "VHD-f210efdf-1916-4c5d-b25c-19cc69814c22"
'
[13816] 2014-03-28 15:12:01.509001  *** lvremove failed on attempt #5
[13816] 2014-03-28 15:12:01.509137  ['/usr/sbin/lvremove', '-f', '/dev/VG_XenStorage-dcd084f1-6074-dc53-e43e-88de1606e09e/VHD-f210efdf-1916-4c5d-b25c-19cc69814c22']
[13816] 2014-03-28 15:12:01.590037  FAILED in util.pread: (rc 5) stdout: '', stderr: '  Can't remove open logical volume "VHD-f210efdf-1916-4c5d-b25c-19cc69814c22"
'
[13816] 2014-03-28 15:12:01.590358  *** lvremove failed on attempt #6
[13816] 2014-03-28 15:12:01.590502  ['/usr/sbin/lvremove', '-f', '/dev/VG_XenStorage-dcd084f1-6074-dc53-e43e-88de1606e09e/VHD-f210efdf-1916-4c5d-b25c-19cc69814c22']
[13816] 2014-03-28 15:12:01.663984  FAILED in util.pread: (rc 5) stdout: '', stderr: '  Can't remove open logical volume "VHD-f210efdf-1916-4c5d-b25c-19cc69814c22"
'
[13816] 2014-03-28 15:12:01.664283  *** lvremove failed on attempt #7
[13816] 2014-03-28 15:12:01.664436  ['/usr/sbin/lvremove', '-f', '/dev/VG_XenStorage-dcd084f1-6074-dc53-e43e-88de1606e09e/VHD-f210efdf-1916-4c5d-b25c-19cc69814c22']
[13816] 2014-03-28 15:12:01.738286  FAILED in util.pread: (rc 5) stdout: '', stderr: '  Can't remove open logical volume "VHD-f210efdf-1916-4c5d-b25c-19cc69814c22"
'
[13816] 2014-03-28 15:12:01.738510  *** lvremove failed on attempt #8
[13816] 2014-03-28 15:12:01.738602  ['/usr/sbin/lvremove', '-f', '/dev/VG_XenStorage-dcd084f1-6074-dc53-e43e-88de1606e09e/VHD-f210efdf-1916-4c5d-b25c-19cc69814c22']
[13816] 2014-03-28 15:12:01.807967  FAILED in util.pread: (rc 5) stdout: '', stderr: '  Can't remove open logical volume "VHD-f210efdf-1916-4c5d-b25c-19cc69814c22"
'
[13816] 2014-03-28 15:12:01.808264  lock: released /var/lock/sm/dcd084f1-6074-dc53-e43e-88de1606e09e/sr
[13816] 2014-03-28 15:12:01.808398  lock: released /var/lock/sm/dcd084f1-6074-dc53-e43e-88de1606e09e/running
[13816] 2014-03-28 15:12:01.808939  SR dcd0 ('Local storage') (20 VDIs in 10 VHD trees): showing only VHD trees that changed:
        9c786065[VHD](150.000G//119.297G|ao)

[13816] 2014-03-28 15:12:01.830139  *~*~*~*~*~*~*~*~*~*~*~*~*~*~*~*~*~*~*~*~*
[13816] 2014-03-28 15:12:01.830212           ***********************
[13816] 2014-03-28 15:12:01.830270           *  E X C E P T I O N  *
[13816] 2014-03-28 15:12:01.830323           ***********************
[13816] 2014-03-28 15:12:01.830390  gc: EXCEPTION util.CommandException, 5
[13816] 2014-03-28 15:12:01.830459    File "/opt/xensource/sm/cleanup.py", line 2514, in gc
    _gc(None, srUuid, dryRun)
  File "/opt/xensource/sm/cleanup.py", line 2416, in _gc
    _gcLoop(sr, dryRun)
  File "/opt/xensource/sm/cleanup.py", line 2386, in _gcLoop
    sr.garbageCollect(dryRun)
  File "/opt/xensource/sm/cleanup.py", line 1437, in garbageCollect
    self.deleteVDIs(vdiList)
  File "/opt/xensource/sm/cleanup.py", line 1451, in deleteVDIs
    self.deleteVDI(vdi)
  File "/opt/xensource/sm/cleanup.py", line 2041, in deleteVDI
    SR.deleteVDI(self, vdi)
  File "/opt/xensource/sm/cleanup.py", line 1460, in deleteVDI
    vdi.delete()
  File "/opt/xensource/sm/cleanup.py", line 982, in delete
    self.sr.lvmCache.remove(self.fileName)
  File "/opt/xensource/sm/lvmcache.py", line 44, in wrapper
    ret = op(self, *args)
  File "/opt/xensource/sm/lvmcache.py", line 108, in remove
    lvutil.remove(path)
  File "/opt/xensource/sm/lvutil.py", line 409, in remove
    _remove(path)
  File "/opt/xensource/sm/lvutil.py", line 419, in _remove
    ret = util.pread2(cmd)
  File "/opt/xensource/sm/util.py", line 178, in pread2
    return pread(cmdlist, quiet = quiet)
  File "/opt/xensource/sm/util.py", line 171, in pread
    raise CommandException(rc, str(cmdlist), stderr.strip())
```

What command needs to be issued to get rid of this?

Comment: I'm having this problem as well.  When I press the reclaim button, I see similar messages in the SMLog.  It's not clear how to resolve this.